# How to update a variable from external javascript file in Angular/Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to update from an Angular project a variable from external javascript file

First I import the variable in my Angular component, and then I try to update it but I don't know how to do it

Little example of my Angular component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { externalText } from './external.js';

...


export class AppComponent  {
  myText = externalText;

  changeText() {

    // This works, but I need to update the variable from external file directly
    this.myText = 'Text updated'

    // I need something like this 
    // externalText = 'Text updated'
  }
}
```

I create this Stackblitz with an example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hczxhh

Expected: be able to update the information in the Javascript file from my Angular component

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] as code in the question itself. This question becomes useless for future readers if/when the link dies.

Comment: You can't save in a file using client-side script, you have to use some server-side scripting like`PHP, NodeJS,.NET` etc. to save something in a file.

Comment: I updated it with some code in the description

Comment: @jitender, it is not possible even if the file is in the same project folder?

Comment: @Jgascona no you will need some server side code using `ts or js` only you can't do this

Comment: @Jgascona Maybe we can write a small backend api which will take the request of what string we want to update from UI and will do the same in that file.

Comment: @Jgascona, I thinks you can't do this. If i were you, build a service to read the property from your external.js or from session cache. If you don't have any in cache them read from external.js. If you want update the value change the cache value.

Comment: Maybe this will works, but as I answered, i solved it by another way. Thanks you @Miguel

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I just created a function in my .js file that overwrites this variable with the content provided by angular. Then I exported this function in order to use it in the Angular component.

Javascript file:

```
export function updateText(myText) {
  externalText = myText
}
```

Angular component:

```
import { externalText, updateText } from './external.js';

export class AppComponent  {
  myText = externalText;

  changeText() {
    updateText('Problem solved')
  }
}
```

Thanks you all a lot for your answers.